# Tesseract in loop sometimes outputs extra digits

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am running tesseract in an infinite loop for debugging purposes to increase the chance of false detections (I am detecting timers on a window), and I notice that fairly frequently tesseract will add an extra digit when there clearly is none. When I save these false detections and rerun it through tesseract, there are no extra digits.

[Here is an example of false detection, where the 16.9 was detected as 1169](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAaEm.jpg)

Running the saved image through again yields 169. Not detecting the decimal point is fine, I can account for that, but extra digits appearing are a real problem.

[Another example. 38.4 was detected as 3584](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2qV5.jpg)

Here is the tesseract config:

```
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang='eng',config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789x.% " --psm 6 --oem 3', output_type=Output.DICT)
```

I have tried psm 6, 7, 11 and 13 with still the same problem. I have tried changing the way I am taking screenshots, still the same problem.

Edit: For now I will simply check the width of the detection but I am still curious if anyone knows what might be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- 1. Upsample the images
- 2. Apply [simple-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Upsampling is needed for accurate recongition of the digits. Thresholding will output the features of the images.

| Threshold (BINARY + OTSU) |
| --- |
| [image] |
| 40% 76% 19.7 60% 16.9 21.8 24.3 x4 |
| [image] |
| 2.1 1.7 9.3 90% 34.1 38.4 6.9 x4 |

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img_lst = ["GAaEm.jpg", "Z2qV5.jpg"]

for img_nm in img_lst:
    img = cv2.imread(img_nm)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
    gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*3, h*3))
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
    print(txt)
    cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```